# how do i get the freindly url?

Tags: c#, winforms

i writen this code
im using it for checking if a certin url is found on a web page

```
    private void checkUrls (){

        WebClient client;

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(txtnum.Text); i++) {
            try
            {
                string Url = "http://www." + txtUrl.Text + i.ToString();

                client = new WebClient();
                string result = client.DownloadString(Url);
                if (result.Contains(txtsearch.Text))
                   MessageBox.Show(Url);

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
```

the base url  look like this:
http://www.example.com/?p=35

but on two sites  when i ask for this:
http://www.example.com/?p=35

i get redirected to somthing  like this
http://www.example.com/some_categoery/postitle/

i need to search the site in the first manner 
but to download  the content of the freindly url

can anyone  show me the right direction to do so ?

i checking  website where  i do no know how many pages there on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/&ei=mzjDTc2PA4zUiALMtImjAw&usg=AFQjCNG2MH29eft1y8OrwFMjVzPNbVc0-w) to get all the anchor tags and check the href attribute for the value you want.